# Extend SCSS class in component

Tags: angular, sass

Alright I've read about this in a few different guides and blogs but I'm struggling to wrap my head around a proper solution for this.

Let's say I have the following classes in my main `styles.scss` file:

```
.btn {
  padding: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.btn--with-image {
  @extends .btn;

  > img {
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
  }
}
```

Now say I have a specific implementation of `btn--with-image` that is unique to a specific angular component. To me, it would make sense to embed the css class in `myComponent.scss`. Let's do that and create it like this:

```
.btn--with-image--google {
  @extends .btn--with-image;

  background-color: blue;
}
```

Now I would think you can add `btn--with-image--google` to an element and you're all set. However, it doesn't work that way. I can't extend `btn--with-images` without re-importing the main `styles.scss` file which duplicates the styles unnecessarily.

What is the proper way to encapsulate the modifier class in the component with minimal duplication?

Answer (score 2):

make a mixin instead

create a file name it mixins.scss

```
@mixin btn-with-image(){
.btn--with-image {
   padding: 5px;
   text-transform: uppercase;

  > img {
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-left: -5px;
   }
  }
}
```

import this to your myComponent.scss

call it like this

```
@include btn-with-image()
```

Hope this helps you, for more info check [this](https://sass-lang.com/guide).